# Embeddding Thumbnail Youtube video

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress

I need embed the thumbnail from a Youtube video and when I clic on the thumbnail the video start to play.
I got the following php code (see php code below) where the video is embedded but I need the code where the thumbnail is embedded too and it starts to play when you clic on the thumnail. I think the code for the video to start playing is the below of the following one (see js code below).

**PHP Code**:

```
<?php
function mininaturas_youtube_func( $atts ) {
$a = shortcode_atts( array(
'id' => ''
), $atts);
return '<iframe width="560" height="315" 
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $a["id"] . '" frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in- 
picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
add_shortcode( 'miniatura_youtube', 'mininaturas_youtube_func' );
?>
```

**Js Code** (my try):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#play").click(function(){
    $("#remove").hide();
    $("#add").show();
  });
});
```

Could you help to include the php code (into the **PHP Code** section) to embedded the thumbnail of the Youtube video and review the js code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By Using this you can embedded thumbnail to video.

Each YouTube video has 4 generated images. They are predictably formatted as follows:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/0.jpg

https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/1.jpg

https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/2.jpg

https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/3.jpg
```

The first one in the list is a full size image and others are thumbnail images. The default thumbnail image (ie. one of 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg) is:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/default.jpg
```

For the high quality version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/hqdefault.jpg
```

There is also a medium quality version of the thumbnail, using a url similar to the HQ:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/mqdefault.jpg
```

For the standard definition version of the thumbnail, use a url similar to this:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/sddefault.jpg
```

For the maximum resolution version of the thumbnail use a url similar to this:

```
https://img.youtube.com/vi/<insert-youtube-video-id-here>/maxresdefault.jpg
```

All of the above urls are available over http too. Additionally, the slightly shorter hostname i3.ytimg.com works in place of img.youtube.com in the example urls above.

[Click For More Answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api)

Comment: Thanks. I knew this info because I read the post you say, previously. The question is how I might integrate the php code I wrote above with the thumbnail Youtube video that I comment. Thanks in advance.